# How and Where to put an API in Codeigniter folder?

Tags: api, codeigniter

How and Where to put an API in Codeigniter folder?

and how to call API with Codeigniter?

thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you looking to write your own API or implement some other app's API for use within your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site has an API, then suitable place to put is some controller in your application/controllers folder, that's how you can respond to the API calls from outside.
Example:

```
class Api extends CI_Controller
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```

If you want to use another API that you want to get responses from, good practice would be to create class in application/libraries/Some_Api.php that will handle the requests and responses to the outside API, of course you will need to call it somewhere in your controllers, models, etc... depending on your needs.

***EDIT***
Example for this would be:

```
class Myapi extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //Here goes your function:
    public function api_call()
    {
        //Some params that Some_Api class will need (if needed of course)
        $params = array('url' => 'https://checkout.google.com', 'username' => 'your_username');

        //Include the library
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Some_Api.php');

        //Create instance of it
        $api = new Some_Api($params);

        //Call the external API and collect the response.
        //In most cases the response is XML and you need to process it as you need it.
        $response = $api->call_some_api_method();

        //Process the response here.
        //Save to database/file, send emails, do whatever you need to.
    }
}
```

Please note that I have used some trivial examples just to explain how the process usually goes. Most of the work should be done in the Some_Api class.
I hope this helps for you!

Comment: thank you for your help. I have another Question. how to call a function of the API in application/libraries/Some_Api.php from within my Controller? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have always had a question about this as well.  I will tell you my approach and I am eager to get feedback.  When including someone else's API I have included it in the model

For example

```
class Model extends CI_Model{

.
. 
.

    function writeLocally{

    //do some stuff


    $this->apiWrite();
    }

    private function apiWrite{

    //api write to 3rd party
    }


}
```

I am guessing this isn't the best approach based on answer above, but anyways that is my two cents.